Rig Veda Suktam for Lord Vishnu
I have been seeing the following portion of 156 Suktam of the 1st Mandala of the Rig Veda being quoted on websites:
"Vishnu is the most ancient of all, yet also the most recent. Nothing and no one creates Vishnu, yet Vishnu creates everyone and everything" - Rig Veda 1.156.2
I want to find out from which translation of the Rig Veda does this come from as it is not translated the same in the versions by Ralph T.H. Griffith or by Stephanie W. Jamison or Brereton
